# Laravel Eloquent relationship mapping issue with three tables and belongsTo() function

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have three tables (instances, users, user_instance).  Each user can be assigned to one instance.  A instance can have many different users.

I try to get the instance_id of from the instance a particular user is assigned to by using Laravel 5.1 Eloquent and belongsTo() function, by calling $this->user->instance->instance_id.

No matter what I've tried, I'm always getting a NULL result in my AuthController.php:

**DB Schema:**

```
    mysql> show columns from instances;
    +------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | name       | varchar(150)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | key        | varchar(150)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | created_at | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | updated_at | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    +------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

    mysql> show columns from users;
    +----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field          | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id             | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | first_name     | varchar(50)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | last_name      | varchar(50)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | email          | varchar(100)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | password       | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | salt           | varchar(255)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | remember_token | varchar(255)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | created_at     | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | updated_at     | int(10)             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | last_login     | int(10) unsigned    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | ip_address     | varchar(15)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | timezone       | int(10)             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | active         | tinyint(1) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    +----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

    mysql> show columns from user_instance;
    +-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id          | int(10) unsigned | YES  | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | user_id     | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | instance_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | created_at  | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | updated_at  | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    +-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**App/Controllers/AuthController.php**

```
    <?php
    use App\Models\User;
    use App\Models\Instance;
    use App\Models\User_Instance;
    class AuthController extends Controller {
    ...
    die($this->user->instance); // Returns: NULL
    ...
    }
    ?>
```

**App/Models/Instance.php**

```
    <?php namespace App\Models;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Instance extends Model
    {
        /**
         * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
         *
         * @var bool
         */
        public $timestamps = true;

        /**
         * The database table used by the model.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $table = 'instances';

        /**
         * The tables primary key.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $primaryKey = 'id';

        /**
         * The attributes that are mass assignable.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $fillable = ['name', 'key', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

        /**
         * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $hidden = [];
    }
    ?>
```

**App/Models/User_Instance.php**

```
    <?php namespace App\Models;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class User_Instance extends Model
    {
        /**
         * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
         *
         * @var bool
         */
        public $timestamps = true;

        /**
         * The database table used by the model.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $table = 'user_instance';

        /**
         * The tables primary key.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $primaryKey = 'id';

        /**
         * The attributes that are mass assignable.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'instance_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

        /**
         * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $hidden = [];
    }
    ?>
```

**App/Models/User.php**

```
    <?php namespace App\Models;

    use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
    use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait;

    class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
    {
        use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword, EntrustUserTrait;

        /**
         * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
         *
         * @var bool
         */
        public $timestamps = true;

        /**
         * The database table used by the model.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $table = 'users';

        /**
         * The tables primary key.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $primaryKey = 'id';

        /**
         * The attributes that are mass assignable.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $fillable = [
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password',
            'salt',
            'remember_token',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
            'last_login',
            'ip_address',
            'timezone',
            'active'
            ];

        /**
         * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

        /**
         * Map the instance with the user.
         *
         * @var int
         */
        public function instance()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User_Instance');
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: In User model you have `instances()` function whereas in AuthController you are calling `instance` i.e without 's'. Can you check its a typo or what..?

Comment: thanks, i've updated that in the description. unfortunately this doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: `die($this->user->instance->instance_id);` in this code `$this->user` will return you the object of `User`. And then you want to get this users related `Instance`. My point is that your `User` model does not have any `instance` method defined.

Comment: thanks so far. i noticed that die(var_dump($this->user)) contains nothing related to "instance" - is this normal behaviour?

Comment: can you show me what var_dump($this->user) returns..?

Comment: var_dump($this->user) returns this http://kopy.io/j2147

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84254/discussion-between-hhsadiq-and-dominic).

Comment: `class User_Instance extends Model
    ...
            public function instance()
            {
                return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User_Instance');
            }`

here you defined that it belongs to self.

Comment: Can you join the chat so that we can have extended discussions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function instance()
{
 return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User_Instance');
}
```

belongsTo , in above method,specifically apply the where condition using snakecase (i.e. instance_id) ..but in your case that would result in wrong result or no result at all ( you want to map on user_id)

As the Laravel - Eloquent suggest .
 if the foreign key on the parent model is not snakecase name (instance_id), you may pass a custom key name as the second argument to the belongsTo method:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User_Instance','user_id');
```

[>>laravel relations](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)